# ppa corrupted removal

Tags: ppa

How to rmove a ppa please ? I want to remove this one 
http://ppa.launchpad.net/george-edison55/cmake-3.x/ubuntu 
Because I cannot update the system because this one does not have release file.

Also when I try to update, I get this error as output

```
File "/usr/bin/lsb_release", line 64
    print("No LSB modules are available.", file=sys.stderr)
                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Updating packages lists
```

Does anyone knows what that means please ?

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

- purge PPA with its packages (if they were installed) with commands below:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
  sudo ppa-purge ppa:george-edison55/cmake-3.x
  ```
- simply remove PPA if you have not installed packages from this PPA with commands below:

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:george-edison55/cmake-3.x
  ```

Then run `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt-get upgrade` again.